# How to merge data frames on top of each other?

Tags: r

I want to merge two datasets so they add on columns.

I've the following dataframe `Hello` that displays teams `Percentage_like` for 2005:

```
Code    Team      Year    Percentage_like
111     Yeroh     2005         43
112     Canvas    2005         32
113     James     2005         23
114     Steve     2005         21
115     Ortney    2005         20
#With 250 more rows
```

And for 2006 the similar dataframe `Hello_2`:

```
Code    Team      Year    Percentage_like
111     Yeroh     2006         36
112     Canvas    2006         25
113     James     2006         34
114     Steve     2006         32
115     Ortney    2006         15
#With 250 more rows
```

**And I would like to just put these data after each other, something like this:**

```
Code    Team      Year    Percentage_like
111     Yeroh     2006         36
112     Canvas    2006         25
113     James     2006         34
114     Steve     2006         32
115     Ortney    2006         15
...      ...      ...         ...
111     Yeroh     2006         36
112     Canvas    2006         25
113     James     2006         34
114     Steve     2006         32
115     Ortney    2006         15
#With more rows
```

I have tried `inner_join(Hello, Hello_2, by = "Year", "Code")` but that creates this dataframe which I don't want:

```
Code    Team.x      Year.x    Percentage_like   Team.y     Year.y    Percentage_like
111     Yeroh     2005         36                Yeroh      2006        43
112     Canvas    2005         25                Canvas     2006        32
113     James     2005         34                James      2006        23
114     Steve     2005         32                Steve      2006        21
115     Ortney    2005         15                Ortney     2006        20
#With 250 more rows
```

Comment: Or: `dplyr::bind_rows(Hello, Hello_2)`.

Comment: No. I just asked the question and nothing more and I was surprised as well. Don't know why that question was apparently that interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This coded solved my problem and merged the two data frames on top of each other `dplyr::bind_rows(Hello, Hello_2)`.

`arrange(year)` makes sure it is sorted by year also.